# integrate dolphin community cms with joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, dolphin-cms

Is there any extensions available with which we can integrate the joomla with dolphin community cms

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a Joomla/Dolphin bridge, but there are a lot of people asking about one. The quickest way to do it would probably be to write a plugin for JFusion since that already integrates with Joomla, half the work is done.